# I do not know what data type to choose for Microsoft SQL Server IDs

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I am creating a database in SQL Server hosted on AWS RDS (I want to use the  2016 or 2017 version).

My question is about the creation of IDs for the tables that I suspect will have many of rows (that's true that probably my database will not have a lot of rows, but I want to learn how to do correctly my work). I do not know what data type is better to choose.

The structure of my id is going to be:

```
[Two items for schema][Three items for tables][Five items for rows]
```

Example that I have been considering:

```
Data type and length | Example    | Storage (bytes)
---------------------+------------+---------------
VARCHAR(10)          | S1TA100001 |   10 bytes 
NUMBER(10,0)         | 0100100001 |    9 bytes
BIGINT               | 100100001  |    8 bytes
```

If I use `VARCHAR`, I have more range (0-9 and A-Z -38-) so maybe I can reduce de ID ([Schema one][Table-one][Row-(tree|four)] that is 5 or 6 bytes that's suppose 54.872 or 2.085.136 rows. But I guess that translates into computing cost.

If I use NUMBER I only have the range (0-9) that is supposed 100.000 rows.

If I use `BIGINT` which has a range of -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). I only use a few of them, but I do not if the computing cost is relevant.

Thank you very much!

Comment: IDs should be tinyint, int or bigint where necessary. Using a varchar as a primary ID column is not as efficient as using an INT

Comment: Another **significant** benefit of a *numerical* ID is that it's **not** dependent on language, regional settings and doesn't come in lowercase vs. mixed case vs. upper case..... I'd **strongly** recommend picking `BIGINT` as the type for your ID

Comment: Agree with BIGINT and @marc_s   Or INT since, if you start with the negative range, it provides an insane number of keys.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be clearly using a **numerical** datatype - preferably `INT` or `BIGINT` - for a database ID.

These types are small, fast, nimble - and they don't have any trouble with lower-/UPPER-case, regional/language settings, Unicode or non-UNicode and many more things that a string-based ID would have. Spare yourself this trouble, if you can!

Whether you need `INT` or `BIGINT` depends on how many rows you expect - 2 billion vs. 9 quintillion :-)

- With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be sufficient for the majority of cases.
  If you use an `INT` (as an `IDENTITY` in SQL Server) starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ...
- If you use a `BIGINT` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows per second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 9.22 quintillion limit ...

Comment: Beware of misjudging things, though -- I've had to upgrade an `INT` column to `BIGINT`. This operation is fairly painful when you have 2 billion rows. Even having to reset an identity with less than 2 billion rows total (because you've processed that many cumulatively) takes some careful consideration. Plan ahead for success!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a natural key, then you should only consider any of the integer data types for your key.

So for large tables, you have to ask yourself if you will exceed 2 billion (or 4 billion if you start at -2147483648). If so, then you should go for `bigint`, otherwise `int` will be enough.

From a performance point of view, `varchar` is much worse due to the more expensive comparison (due to case and accent insensitivity)

`decimal` is just marginally slower than `bigint`. Since `decimal` requires more space, you never need it for generated key.